# I cant add latitude and longitude to an input in html

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys I try to add the latitude and longitude from my current location to an input.

Do you have any idea of what to do? this is my code

```
<input type="text" name="demo" id="demo" value="<?php echo $demo ;?>" />
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").value=latitude;
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else{
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {   
 latitude.innerHTML= position.coords.latitude; 
 longitude.innerHTML=position.coords.longitude;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: @Teemu: with respect to return value the parameter is a function that assigns stuff.

Comment: I have a button to call the function getLocation();

Comment: what is latitude? at the beginning of your script you are setting the input value to `latitude` which leads me to believe it should be text of some kind but later on in the `showPosition` function you seem to be setting its inner HTML suggesting it is a DOM element. Perhaps you should be more precise about what you think this should be and indeed more precise about what problem you are having exactly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Latitude/Longitude Button to Fill Input Boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067389/get-latitude-longitude-button-to-fill-input-boxes)

Comment: Additionally when this seems to be a duplicate of the very first item in the "Related" questions list on the side it suggests you haven't done much to actually research what you are doing yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I did not understand, but if your intention is to add the coordinates to the text field try this

```
<body>
<script>
function getLocation(){
  if (navigator.geolocation){
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }else{
       alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }
 getLocation()
function showPosition(position) {
      var str="Longitude:"+ position.coords.longitude+"Latitude:"+ position.coords.latitude
      document.getElementById("demo").value=str
  }
</script>
<input type="text" name="demo" id="demo" value="" />
</body>
```